# How to handle events of a button rendered using jquery and handlebars from a react component that is built separately?

Tags: reactjs

Recently I am integrating a react component into a website with pages that are rendered using jquery + handlebars.
 A part of the website has a product list which is rendered using jquery+handle bars as mentioned, each item in the product list has a button

What I am trying to achieve is to handle the click event of the buttons in the jquery rendered product list within the reactjs application/component.

how do I achieve this? thanks

eg , assuming this is my product list rendered using handle bars + jquery in a nodejs application

```
<ul>
  <li><button class="message">message</button></li>
 <li><button class="message">message</button></li>
 <li><button class="message">message</button></li>
</ul>
```

and then I have a separately built react application/ component, created using create-react-app. How do I access the dom and handle the click events of those buttons, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just the same way as from framework-less JS. You can do it in one of your React component's life-cycle methods, for example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.querySelector("button.message...").addEventListener("click", event => 
    this.handleMessageButtonClick())
}
```

You'll need a way to distinguish the multiple buttons with `class="message"`, though.
And don't forget to remove the listener in `componentWillUnmount()`